# Can bloated CacheStorage slow down Service Worker responses?

Tags: performance, service-worker, workbox, cachestorage

I am caching opaque responses in SW which bloats `CacheStorage` exponentially upto order of 6 GB+. At times, I see SW responses slower than that from the browser cache.
Can bloated CacheStorage lead to slow read and hence degraded performance while serving request through SW? How much of this performance is driven by what kind of hard drive the machine is loaded with -- SSD vs HDD?

PS: I am aware that the ideal fix is to either fix the opaque responses or not cache them at all.

Comment: Opaque response are obfuscated code so, yeah, it might slow down your SW because it need to "read" obfucated data to know if it's file you need or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cache Storage API gives you programmatic control over cache expiration, and allows you to use cached responses within JavaScript to construct complex serving/fallback strategies that work independent of the network, which is generally speaking not possible when just using the browser's HTTP cache.

There is no specific expectation that using the Cache Storage API is going to be *faster* than the HTTP cache, though.

There's some degree of overhead involved whenever service worker code is run, and the details about that overhead's impact are likely to vary based on storage medium, CPU, browser version, and any number of other criteria. I will say that I don't believe the fact that these are opaque responses comes that heavily into play when it comes to runtime performance, and the additional quota usage is effectively "fictitious". It just translates into a higher number used when calculating available quota, but does not actually result in more data being written to disk.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! It makes sense that caching opaque responses exposes us to the risk of running out of StorageQuota, thereby preventing any further caching of resources.
By the Storage medium, does it mean that if we have two machines with SSD and HDD, SW response can be faster than network in SSD, but slower in machine with HDD? Do we always read from the disk? Or is there some optimization by bringing CacheStorage data in memory?

Comment: I would assume that everything is going to be faster if you're working off of a SSD rather than a HDD. Even things that should ostensibly be in memory get paged out to disk fairly frequently as part of virtual memory schemes, right? But there are so many variables at play here that I don't feel qualified to speak with authority about many scenarios.

Comment: Correct! I think knowing how CacheStorage works under the hood might help us unveil some of the secrets.

Comment: (Please keep in mind that Firefox, Safari, and Chrome/Edge each support service workers + the Cache Storage API, yet each have very different codebases. So even if you learned about one implementation, your observations won't necessarily apply to the other browsers.)